# What are the differences between these ways of selecting element in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

If I have the following markup

```
<div id="previewNote" class="note yellow" style="left:25;top:25px;z-index:1;">
   <div class="body"></div>
   <div class="author"></div>
   <span class="data"></span>
</div>
```

I can select the "previewNote" DIV either by using

```
$("#previewNote")
```

or

```
$("[ID$=previewNote]")
```

and with even other ways. When my element is inside a dialog window usually the first method does not work but the second does.

Which are the differences between the two?

thanks!

Comment: Yes. ASP.NET MVC 2 to be precise...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("#previewNote")` selects element whose `id` is `previewNote`
`$("[ID$=previewNote]")` selects element whose `id` ***ends with*** (`$`) `previewNote`

More Info: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/

Comment: Thanks! Could you please give more info on why using the first method does not work when I am inside a dialog and the element is inside the dialog itself?